# Selecting column on the basis of date

Tags: python-3.x, multi-index

I have the following data set.

```
ID  Date         description V1  V2  V3
1   31-Jan-2013  Des1         10 20  30
1   31-Jan-2013  Des2         20 30 20
1   31-jan-2014  Des1         56 30 20
1   31-jan-2014  des2         30 40 60
2   31-dec-2013  Decc1         10 20  30
2   31-dec-2013  Decc2         20 30 20
2   31-dec-2014  Decc1         56 30 20
2   31-dec-2014  decc2         30 40 60
```

I want extract only the latest year values for the ID's.

expected output.

```
ID  Date         description V1  V2  V3
1   31-jan-2014  Des1         56 30 20
1   31-jan-2014  des2         30 40 60
2   31-dec-2014  Decc1         56 30 20
2   31-dec-2014  decc2         30 40 60
```

Can anybody help, how we can achieve this in pandas.

Thanks
Anubhav

- may be use groupby().

```
    data_u.set_index(['ID', 'Date'],inplace=True)
    data_u.sort_index(inplace=True)

    data_u.groupby(data_u.index).index.agg(['count'])
```

this gives me count of the rows of multindex.

But I want to select the latest year of all ID's. Number of records are >500000

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df[df.apply(lambda x : x['Date'] == df[(df['ID'] == x['ID'])]['Date'].max() , axis =1)]
```

**Output**

```
+---+----+------------+-------------+----+----+----+
|   | ID |    Date    | description | V1 | V2 | V3 |
+---+----+------------+-------------+----+----+----+
| 2 |  1 | 2014-01-31 | Des1        | 56 | 30 | 20 |
| 3 |  1 | 2014-01-31 | des2        | 30 | 40 | 60 |
| 6 |  2 | 2014-12-31 | Decc1       | 56 | 30 | 20 |
| 7 |  2 | 2014-12-31 | decc2       | 30 | 40 | 60 |
+---+----+------------+-------------+----+----+----+
```